# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using Twilio JavaI420Buffer (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface, buffer, twilio-video

#### Description

When trying to allocate JavaI420Buffer via the following call:

```
tvi.webrtc.JavaI420Buffer.allocate(width, height)
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.nio.ByteBuffer tvi.webrtc.JniCommon.nativeAllocateByteBuffer(int) (tried Java_tvi_webrtc_JniCommon_nativeAllocateByteBuffer and Java_tvi_webrtc_JniCommon_nativeAllocateByteBuffer__I)
        at tvi.webrtc.JniCommon.nativeAllocateByteBuffer(Native Method)
        at tvi.webrtc.JavaI420Buffer.allocate(JavaI420Buffer.java:87)
        at dji.ux.beta.core.widget.fpv.FPVWidget$onSurfaceTextureAvailable$yuvDataListener$1.onYuvDataReceived(FPVWidget.kt:417)
```

Before this error I also get:

```
2021-05-28 08:31:27.367 15131-15131/? I/tvi.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: Loading native library: jingle_peerconnection_so
2021-05-28 08:31:27.367 15131-15131/? I/tvi.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: Loading library: jingle_peerconnection_so
2021-05-28 08:31:27.369 15131-15131/? E/tvi.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: Failed to load native library: jingle_peerconnection_so
2021-05-28 08:31:27.369 15131-15131/? E/tvi.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" not found
2021-05-28 08:31:27.370 15131-15131/? E/tvi.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" not found
```

Strangely if I declare to use official org.webrtc library (`implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'`) then native call to allocate byte buffer succeeds.

#### Video Android SDK Version

`com.twilio:video-android-ktx:6.3.0`

Comment: I am also facing same issue for scanLibrary if I convert it in kotlin otherwise it's working in java with static block. Let me know if you found any solution

Comment: are you using proguard?

Comment: No, that was actually the first thing to do after I got this issue, disabling proguard. But that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Could you confirm if the `jingle_peerconnection.so` packaged for all ABIs (arm, arm64, x86, x86_64) in your apk? You could drop the apk in Studio and check under `libs/<ABI>` path

Answer (score 0):

> First of all when you load native code in kotlin it should be like this:

```
companion object {
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("jingle_peerconnection")
    }
}
```

> In Java

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jingle_peerconnection")
}
```

> Second as per your error, **"library "libjingle_peerconnection_so.so"** not found => you have to add related Android architectures folder in "**main -> java -> libs**" folder

```
Example : main -> java -> libs -> x86 -> .so file
```

Comment: Tried loading via `companion object` call but it did not work. Not sure though why I would need to do that, because when using `org.webrtc` version I don't have to load anything. Seems more like a library issue for Kotlin?

Comment: possible because same thing happens to me for "scanLibrary". If I convert code in kotlin it's not working and giving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. While if I convert code in java then it's working with "static" block.

Comment: I've opened an issue at Github library page https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/643, as I think this is something related to native build jingle_peerconnection_so.so file.